# Why does MATCH AGAINST return different results than LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search, sql-like

I am comparing the results of a query like

```
SELECT * FROM object_search
WHERE
    keywords LIKE '%,woman,%'
AND keywords LIKE '%,man,%'
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM object_search
WHERE
    MATCH (keywords) AGAINST ('+(",woman,") +(",man,")')
```

I would have expected the exact same results, but the first query spits out about 300 results and the second one close to 3000.

What is the difference inbetween the two and how do I get the same result using the fulltext functionality?

Comment: Could you provide structure of your table? And also some rows which were returned in 2-nd case, but not if 1-st.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo It seems like the `MATCH AGAINST` query only requires one of the two keywords to be present in a row. Also it's an InnoDB table.

Comment: My guess is that it is about your `woman` and `man` words since `man` is subword of `woman` (but it seems that's not how it should work). Try something like `foo` and `bar` instead - i.e. non-intersective

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Still the same with `car` and `house`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator is used in searches [`IN BOOLEAN MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html). I *think* it will be ignored in `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` (default).

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM object_search
WHERE MATCH (keywords)
    AGAINST ('+woman +man' IN BOOLEAN MODE); -- could return rows containing both "man" and "woman" (ignoring ft_min_word_len, see below)
```

Besides, fulltext indexes will cover words only. Punctuation signs (such as `,`) will always be ignored. You cannot "fulltext-search" non-alphanumeric characters.

Finally, by default, words shorter than 4 characters are ignored. Therefore, by default, "man" is not indexed. This limit can be changed through the [`ft_min_word_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) configuration option.

Also, mind the [stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) (common words that are never indexed).

Comment: @Cobra_Fast If still possible, rethink your table structure. Storing coma-separated values (i.e. non-scalar data) in one single field is bad practice. [Normalize your structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) if you can.